# Añadir valor a columnas de un GridView por medio de query

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, telerik

Mi problema es que necesito rellenar un **RadGridView**, con su propio `DataSource` en el que tengo columnas con datos y otras columnas que no tienen, en estas columnas sin datos necesito insertarlos por medio de un *query*, ¿es esto posible de algún modo?

Lo que había intentado es recorrer las filas del *grid* e igualar el valor de las columnas a la *query*, pero no es posible.

```
private void RecorrerGrid()
{
    try
    {
        foreach(GridViewRowInfo row in radGridView1.Rows)
        {
            switch (row.Cells["Tipo_Tarea"].Value)
            {
                case "PI":
                    row.Cells["Referencia_Pedido_Cliente"].Value = 
                    "SELECT COALESCE(PED.REFERENCIA,'')AS Referencia_Pedido_Cliente FROM DBO.TBLTAREASPENDIENTES AS TP LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.TBLORDENRECOGIDALIN AS LN ON LN.IDORDENRECOGIDA = CAST(TP.TAREA AS INTEGER)  LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.TBLPEDIDOSCLICAB AS PED ON PED.IDPEDIDOCLI =LN.IDPEDIDOCLI  LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.TBLRUTAS AS R ON PED.IDRUTA = R.IDRUTA  LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.TBLCLIENTES AS C ON PED.IDCLIENTE = C.IDCLIENTE WHERE(TP.TIPOTAREA= 'PI')";
                break;
```

Comment: Bienvenido Osma. Una pregunta, ¿Te has planteado usar un GridObject como DataSource?

Dicho de otro modo, ¿Por qué no creas una clase dedicada para ese RadGridView? Si lo haces así, una clase que que contenga todas las columnas ya no tendrás que preocuparte sobre que columnas tienen datos y cuales no, ya que el DataSource (es decir, la clase que rellene la grid) tendrá las columnas que necesites.

O si no, cuando cargues la grid en tiempo de ejecución, creas las columnas de forma "unbound" y las rellenas al cargar la pantalla, aunque el proceso es bastante lento...

Comment: La cosa es que al principio esas columnas tienen que estar vacias y al darle a un botón se tienen que rellenar cada columna con su query.

Comment: Buenas compañero, desconozco los controles telerik, pero al GridView de .Net puedes poner como DataSource un DataTable, que es la representación de una tabla, y ahí, puedes modificar los datos y que sean visibles para el usuario y poderlos tratar posteriormente si es necesario, ¿es lo que buscabas?
Si puedes, adjunta código para indicar qué es lo que intentas hacer y qué es lo que no te está funcionando.

Comment: Sea como fuere, si dices que esas columnas tienen que estar vacias pero al pulsar un botón se tienen que rellenar, esas columnas tienen que existir sí o sí. Por eso decía la solución del GridObject. Como se rellenen, hazlo con el evento del botón una vez hagas click.

Comment: Principalmente las columnas no son llamadas como campos reales de la base de datos, por lo tanto lo que quiero es recorrer las filas del grid además paso por cierto switch y ahi es donde quiero igualar las columnas a sus querys correspondientes.